# jQuery Table AddRow Plugin adding ID numbers to added rows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form and I'm using the jQuery Table AddRow plugin to dynamically add rows to a table, the problem is I'm trying to when you select a Menu Item that the menu item goes into the text box to the left of it. It works on the first row but I can't figure out how to get it to work with rows that are added via the plugin.

You can see my code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/VXNzd/

Here is the jQuery code:

```
// This moves the select box text to the input box
$('#mnu_names').change(function() {
    var mnuProduct = $("#mnu_names").find(':selected').text();
    var mnuCleanProduct = mnuProduct.split(' - ');
    $('#topping_name').attr('value', mnuCleanProduct[0]);
});
// This code is needed to add and delete rows with the plugin
$(".toppings_add").btnAddRow({
```

It may be easier to see what I'm talking about by visiting the jsfiddle link up top. When it loads use the select box to and select something, It will put that info over into the text box without the price info. Add a new row and try it again. Won't work, can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for posting the jsfiddle. I can't immediately see your problem but be careful with using `#topping_name` which is an ID vs. `.topping_name` which is a class. You shouldn't have more than one unique ID on a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was as said by tomhallam your ID's are not unique.  Also `$.change()` does not work on blocks added after you ran that.  You should instead use `$.on('change',...)`.

I updated your code and posted it on http://jsfiddle.net/PDPbn/5/.

The modified jquery-code goes as follows:

```
$(document).on('change','.mnu_names',function() {
    var mnuProduct = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    var mnuCleanProduct = mnuProduct.split(' - ');
    $(this).parentsUntil('tbody').find('.topping_name').attr('value', mnuCleanProduct[0]);
});
```

Comment: Taken from jQuery documentation: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.` In that case one could look into the method which adds the new line item and attach the required event at that time to the new object. Using depricated methods might lead to unsupported and unstable code later.

Comment: Thank you Zombaya, as for the ID's, I don't know how Table AddRow handles them but I am only using there examples to build the form. I don't have any formal jQuery edu just using and playing with what I can find.

Comment: From what I've seen, AddRow just copies the existing row, that's why you get un-unique id's.

Comment: OK now I see what you all were talking about. LOL copied the JS over but not the new form and it wouldn't work then I saw the ID's changed to classes. I do see what you all mean though with the ID's and the cloning of the row by Table AddRow though. Thank again