# how to create dynamic inputs in a form?

Tags: jquery, forms

```
<form id="myForm">

<select name="team_home" id="team_home_0">
    <option></option>
    <option value="italy">italy</option>
    <option value="spain">spain</option>
    <option value="germany">germany</option>
    <option value="france">france</option>
    <option value="portugal">portugal</option>
    <option value="england">england</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="result_0" />
<select name="team_visit" id="team_visit_0">
    <option></option>
    <option value="italy">italy</option>
    <option value="spain">spain</option>
    <option value="germany">germany</option>
    <option value="france">france</option>
    <option value="portugal">portugal</option>
    <option value="england">england</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The point is get an output like this:

[image]

Everytime that a whole line of inputs is completed, then should "appear" a new empty line of inputs to do the same process. It never ends (the dynamic creation), so the teams and results can be repeated infinitely.

I know I should use jQuery, but i didn't figure it out how.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6hLy9/)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jqformhelper/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385484/jquery-table-addrow-plugin-adding-id-numbers-to-added-rows

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145012/adding-rows-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: this is in one and the same form huh? that makes determining when the user is finished difficult, why not append a new form for each row after the user "submitted" the row via `on('click', function(){$('#formcontainer').append(formstring);});`

Comment: Oops, its the same form, let me edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with some of the beginnings of the ID increments in place.  You can see if this helps you get started.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmd97/Vk5xJ/

```
function appendTo(index) {
     var s = a new row of inputs with dynamic index
     $("#container").append(s);
     addClick(index);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. You'll need to enhance it to increment the group ID, reset inputs, etc.

http://api.jquery.com/clone

http://jsfiddle.net/6hLy9/9

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="group1" class="group">
        <select name="team_home" class="team_home" id="team_home_0">
            <option></option>
            ...
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="result" id="result_0" />
        <select name="team_visit" class="team_visit" id="team_visit_0">
            <option></option>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

$('select, input').on('change', function () {
    var emptyEls = false;
    var thisEl = $(this).parents('.group');
    $(this).siblings().each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            emptyEls = true;
        }
    });
    if (emptyEls == false) {
        $(thisEl).clone().appendTo('#wrapper');
    }
});
```